# Invalid operation.The connection is closed error while reading from SQL server

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I like to read from database using Linq to SQL. However in this method throw exception

```
  public string[] readFromAbbrevationsPerson()
{
    string[] resultAbbrevationsPerson = new string[10000];


    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext("NERMacedonianConnectionString");

    var query = from abb in db.abbrevationsPersons
                select abb.abbrevationsPerson1;
    int i = 0;

    foreach (string noun in query)
        resultAbbrevationsPerson[i++] = noun;

    return resultAbbrevationsPerson;
}
```

in the foreach statement.The exception is Invalid operation the connection is closed.
I made refresh in VS 2010 to the server and I made refresh in SQL Management studio.Ichecked the status of the server is running.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the full connection string to the constructor for `DataClassesDataContext(string connection)`, unless you've created your own constructor which just takes a value like what you've entered. The exception in this case is not very helpful in determining the cause.

Comment: +1, I had this error pop up because there was a problem in my connection string (missing a ";").